# Is there a way to multiply bamboo shoots?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

When visiting the bamboo mystery island, you can retrieve bamboo shoot by digging in the ground.
When back on your island, planting the bamboo shoot will give a bamboo tree after a few days, as well as another bamboo shoot next to it. However, it's 1:1 for the shoot and it doesn't seem there are more shoots afterwards from this bamboo tree.
Planting an already grown tree from the mystery island to your island doesn't give another bamboo shoot.

Did I miss something or is the bamboo island the only way to get additional bamboo shoots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying bamboo shoots are a 1:1 return. Once a bamboo fully grows and generates shoots, it's only once.

That said, there is another way to get shoots... buy Turnips on Sunday mornings!

After you purchase turnips, you might receive mail the next day from Daisy thanking you for the business with a handful of bamboo shoots attached.

Comment: OK, will just have to wait then for some more shoots, as I'm quite investing in turnips for a couple weeks now :)